# Haw to deserialize Json response if the number of fields from the response not known?

Tags: c#, json

Since I don't now how many fields the json response will have I can't hard code the class to match the json object. What is the best practice to deserialize json to object in this case?

Comment: using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

Comment: if the service you are querying is documented enough you can just declare a class containing ALL possible fields. If using Newtonsoft.Json (not sure about the inbuilt JSON parser) it will only populate the fileds filled in the JSON document, and you can enven add some custom logic to null handling during deserialization

Comment: You should make your coupling to the response as loose as possible. I.e. don't make it so you need to understand everything in it, since that will prevent the service from being extended later on. Create a class with the fields you need and ignore the rest.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the JSON that you are trying to deserialize?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know number of fields, only whay is dynamic object.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(jsonstring);
```